# Automator action not supplied with the required data

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, file, macos

I'm trying to do the following in an Automator workflow:

1. Ask for Finder items from folder A
2. In folder A, add a *suffix* to the file names
3. Copy them to folder B
4. In folder B, with an AppleScript, split the file name by a delimiter and then rename the file with the second half of the text split
5. In folder B, add a *prefix* to the file names
6. In folder B, add a *suffix* to the file names

Here is a sample of the file names I'm trying to rename:

- a new file$SG789.jpg
- file_2$123-456.jpg
- file_name$LG123.jpg
- this_file$558-432.jpg

The delimiter I'm splitting by is the "$" dollar sign to create the following new files:

- SG789.jpg
- 123-456.jpg
- LG123.jpg
- 558-432.jpg

These are the file name formats I'd like for the automator to continue processing.

Thanks to another user, I was able to get this far. However, my workflow is failing at step 5. I'm getting the following warning:

*The action "Rename Finder Items: Add Text" was not supplied with the required data.*

Here is the workflow setup in Automator:

[image]

With the AppleScript below:

```
 on run {input, parameters}
     try
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "$"
        set output to {}
        repeat with anItem in input
            set the end of output to text item 2 of (anItem as text)
        end repeat
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
        return output
    on error eStr number eNum
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with icon caution
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
        return
    end try
end run
```

I thought by returning output, the next workflow would pick up and continue with the required changes. I'm seeing that is not the case.

How do I return my output so that the next workflow item can use it and continue with the file renaming?

Comment: You said, "_I thought by returning output, the next workflow would pick up and continue with the required changes. I'm seeing that is not the case._" and what's being returned by the AppleScript action is just a list of filenames, not the fully qualified pathnames, and while it could be modified to return the FQP, it still will not work with the next action because it's just a list of text strings, not filesystem objects as was passed to the AppleScript action. In the AppleScript action the FSO's were coerced to text strings in order to process as text items, i.e. `(anItem as text)`.

Comment: You said "_How do I return my output so that the next workflow item can use it and continue with the file renaming?_", I do not know if there is a way to achieve what you are trying to do with the AppleScript action. That said, why are you modifying the original files before copying them, that just doesn't make sense. I'd swap Rename Finder Items: Add Text with Copy Finder Items. Anyway, it's not clear to me why you're going through so many different steps if all you're trying to do is rename a file e.g. `a new file$SG789.jpg` to `SG789.jpg`.

Comment: I'd probably opt for doing this with a bash script, IMO it would be much easier and more efficient. Another option is to get the FSO's, pass them to the AppleScript action and programmatically do everything else that needs  to be done to the FSO's within the AppleScript _code_.  (Which of course will require additional coding.)

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you for the explanation. It makes sense.

Comment: @user3439894 The reason I'm modifying the originals is because I need to keep a record of what files were processed, since my workflow strips out the name and just leaves what looks like random characters. If you have an alternative suggestion to keeping track of the original files already proccessed, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I do not know whether or not you've seen the answer I originally posted, however I've updated it, adding updated _code_ for the Run Shell Script action in the original Automator workflow, and added a second Automator workflow. Just read the section under **Update:** New _code_ for **Run Shell Script** _action:_ and also below **Second Automator Workflow** for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is still not totally clear what it is you're trying to accomplish, however, here is an example *workflow* that you might find useful.

## **First Automator Workflow**

- Broken into two working segments:

## **First Segment:**

- **Ask for Finder Items**
- **Rename Finder Items: Add Text**
- **Copy Finder Items**
- **Run Shell Script**

  - Settings: **Shell: bin/bash** *and* **Pass input: as arguments**

    - Replace the *default code* with the *code* below.
    - This is what's used to remove *up to and including the* `$` in the *basename* of the *filename*.

Code for **Run Shell Script** *action*:

```
cd "$(dirname "$1")"
for f in "$@"
do
    mv "$(basename "$f")" "$(printf "$(basename "$f")" | sed -E 's/^.*\$//')"
done
echo "$(ls -1)"
```

- **Note:** The `echo "$(ls -1)"` *command* is not really necessary in this *use case* and was used in this example just to show the filenames had been changed and to show that in the Results *pane*.

---

- **Update:** New code for **Run Shell Script** *action*:
  Use this *code* instead of the original *code*, above. I've modified it to be a bit more efficient having to call `basename` once, instead of twice. (I have not updated the *code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* in the original image below.)

  ```
  cd "$(dirname "$1")"
  for f in "$@"; do
      n="$(basename "$f")"
      mv "$n" "$(printf "$n" | sed -E 's/^.*\$//')"
  done
  echo "$(ls -1)"
  ```
- **Note:** See also the second **Automator** *workflow*, shown after the original image below, which negates the need for the **Second Segment:**, as its **Run Shell Script** *action* is coded to handle the renaming that takes place in the second segment, adding `prefix-` and swapping `-proc` for `-suffix`.

---

## **Second Segment:**

- **Ask for Finder Items**

  - Options: **[√] Ignore this action's input**

    - By checking this option you'll see, in the image below, there is a wanted disconnect between the previous action and this one.
- **Rename Finder Items: Add Text**
- **Rename Finder Items: Add Text**

See the image below for other applicable settings of **Automator** *actions*, as shown in the OP.

As you can see in the image below, all *actions* completed successfully and did as programed, with the Results pane of each *action* showing the results of it's *action*.

---

[image: First Automator Workflow]

---

## **Second Automator Workflow**

<sup>To be used instead of the First Automator Workflow.</sup>

- **Ask for Finder Items**
- **Rename Finder Items: Add Text**
- **Copy Finder Items**
- **Run Shell Script**

  - Settings: **Shell: bin/bash** *and* **Pass input: as arguments**

    - Replace the *default code* with the *code* below the image.

[image: Second Automator Workflow]

- The results of the first three *actions* in this second **Automator** *workflow* are the exact same as shown in the first *workflow* above, therefore I've left the **Results** *pane* hidden for these *actions*. However, the **Results** *pane* for the **Run Shell Script** *action* shows the wanted results.

Code for **Run Shell Script** *action* in the Second Automator Workflow:

```
p='prefix-'
s='-suffix'
t='-proc'

cd "$(dirname "$1")"
for f in "$@"; do
    n="$(basename "$f")"
    if [[ $n =~ ^.*\$.*${t}\.${n##*.} ]]; then
        mv "$n" "${p}$(printf "${n%.*}" | sed -E -e "s/$t/$s/" -e 's/^.*\$//').${n##*.}"
    fi
done
echo "$(ls -1)"
```

- Update Note: I've modified the *code* by placing the *variable* assignments outside of the `for` *loop*, as that is the only *code* you should need/want to modify as necessary (and they don't need to be within the `for` *loop*). I have not updated the image of the Automator *workflow* to reflect this update.

---

You could, if needed/wanted, add a different second segment to this second *workflow*, but the *code* in this  **Run Shell Script** *action* eliminates the need for the two **Rename Finder Items: Add Text** *actions* that were in the second segment of the first (original), *workflow*.

Note: I will update this with an explanation of what the *code* is doing in **Run Shell Script** *action*, as soon as I can.

Comment: The second workflow automation definitely does the job. I also see why you felt I had too many steps, considering the rest of the renaming could have been done in a script. Thank you.

Comment: @Yazmin, I haven't had time yet to update the answer with an explanation of what the _code_ in the _bash script_ is doing, but will as soon as I get a chance. Suffice it to say you should only have to modify the _value_ of the three _variables_ `p`, `s` and `t` as needed/wanted. The remaining _code_ should not need to be modified.

Comment: @Yazmin, Update Note: I've modified the _code_, in the second Automator _workflow_, by placing the _variable_ assignments outside of the `for` _loop_, as that is the only _code_ you should need/want to modify as necessary (and they don't need to be within the `for` _loop_). I have not updated the image of the Automator _workflow_ to reflect this update.